# Insert data with a SUBSTRING in the SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

How do I `INSERT` data with a `SUBSTRING` in the `SELECT`?

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
INSERT INTO PHONE( 
        ID_CLIENT,
        COD,
        PHONE) 
 SELECT (ID_CLI,
        SUBSTRING(PHONE,0,3), '',
        SUBSTRING(PHONE,3,9), '')
 FROM [dbo].TABLE_1
 WHERE ID_PHONE = 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should have your keyboard replaced. It seems to be stuck with CAPS LOCK ON. Now STOP SHOUTING AT US!!!

Comment: Please refrain from using ALL CAPS.

Comment: Your select statement has 5 columns and the insert has 3

Comment: What was the error message you received?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO PHONE(     
    ID_CLIENT,    
    COD,       
    PHONE) 
SELECT (ID_CLI,    
    SUBSTRING(PHONE,0,3),    
    SUBSTRING(PHONE,3,9)    
 FROM [dbo].TABLE_1    
 WHERE ID_PHONE = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL is not like other languages. When counting a string, the count does not begin at zero, like python and other similar languages, it begins at 1. I noticed, in your substring() function, you inserted the starting value as 0. This would be correct in some languages, but in SQL the first character is 1 not zero. Also, after the last substring, be sure to close your () from the original select statement. You opened () after the select, before the ID_CLI column, but did not provide a closing () at the end of the statement. I am not a professional with this language, by any means, but I hope my input is helpful for what you are trying to do. I believe this may work, if not there may be something I am missing, (again, I am a novice with SQL, so forgive me if this is not correct)

```
INSERT INTO PHONE(     
    ID_CLIENT,    
    COD,       
    PHONE) 
SELECT (ID_CLI,    
    SUBSTRING(PHONE,1,4),    
    SUBSTRING(PHONE,4,10))    
FROM [dbo].TABLE_1    
WHERE ID_PHONE = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are selecting five columns and trying to insert into three columns in another table. Make sure the number of rows match. It appears that you may be trying to concatenate the substrings with empty strings, which you would need to use the CONCAT function for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
WITH CteData
AS
(
 SELECT ID_CLI,SUBSTRING(PHONE,0,3) AS COD,SUBSTRING(PHONE,3,9) AS PHONE
FROM [dbo].TABLE_1
WHERE ID_PHONE = 2
)
INSERT INTO PHONE(ID_CLIENT,COD,PHONE) 
SELECT CteData.ID_CLI,CteData.COD,CteData.PHONE FROM CteData
```

but first you need to remove the empty space like '' which create the impression for the INSERT statement that you have more columns on the SELECT than the INSERT, I did use CTE just to make the code readable